# Jhipster fails with: "[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /management/info from localhost:9000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED)"

Tags: jhipster, code-generation

I am trying to create a simple project skeleton using `jhipster`.

```
# Ubuntu 18.04
node -v
# v10.15.1
npm -v
# 6.4.1
jhipster --version
# 6.0.0
jhipster
# (I only press enter, so that the defaults are selected)
npm start
```

Now I access the application on port 9000, but when I try to login with `admin`/`admin` as prompted, it fails

```
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /management/info from localhost:9000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/account from localhost:9000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
[HPM] Error occurred while trying to proxy request /api/authenticate from localhost:9000 to http://localhost:8080 (ECONNREFUSED) (https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors)
```

The same when I try to register a new user from the app.

Is this a bug of the application, or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You aren't launching the backend. https://www.jhipster.tech/development/#running-java-server

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are only running the frontend, you also need to start backend as @Jon Ruddell comments. On the application directory you have to run:

`./mvnw` (or `mvnw` if you are on Windows).

> **Running the Java server**
>
> *As a “main” Java class*
>
> From your IDE,
> right-click on the “Application” class at the root of your Java
> package hierarchy, and run it directly. You should also be able to
> debug it as easily.
>
> The application will be available on http://localhost:8080.
>
> This application will have “hot reload” enabled by default, so if you
> compile a class, the Spring application context should refresh itself
> automatically, without the need to restart the server.
>
> *As a Maven project*
>
> You can launch the Java server with Maven. JHipster
> provides a Maven wrapper, so you don’t need to install Maven, and you
> have the guarantee that all project users have the same Maven version:
>
> ./mvnw (on Mac OS X/Linux) of mvnw (on Windows)
>
> (this will run our default Maven task, spring-boot:run)
>
> The application will be available on http://localhost:8080.
>
> Alternatively, if you have installed Maven, you can launch the Java
> server with Maven:
>
> mvn
>
> If you want more information on using Maven, please go to
> http://maven.apache.org
>
> *(Optional) As a Gradle project*
>
> If you selected the Gradle option,
> JHipster provides a Gradle wrapper, so you don’t need to install
> Gradle, and you have the guarantee that all project users have the
> same Gradle version:
>
> ./gradlew (on Mac OS X/Linux) of gradlew (on Windows)
>
> (this will run our default Gradle task, bootRun)
>
> Alternatively, if you have installed Gradle, you can launch the Java
> server with Gradle:
>
> gradle
>
> The application will be available on http://localhost:8080.
>
> If you want more information on using Gradle, please go to
> https://gradle.org

source: https://www.jhipster.tech/development/

Comment: Excellent answer. Thanks.